# How to sort concat_ws(',',collect_list(a)) in MySQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, concatenation, aggregate-functions

I have a table with 2 columns time and text, where I want to concatenate text by the order of time.

I presto sql, I can do `ARRAY_AGG(text ORDER BY time)`, how can I do it in MySQL?
I found `CONCAT_WS(',', COLLECT_LIST(text))` can do partial work, but not sure how to order by time in a quick way.

Thank you.

Comment: Mistake here, I want the query execute in SparkSQL

Answer (score 0):

You would use:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(test ORDER BY time)
```

Note:  This produces a comma-delimited string, not an array.

Comment: May I ask one more question regrading to it, I tried but I receive this error 'org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'ORDER' expecting {')', ','}(line 3, pos 41)'. I am using SparkSQL, and my code is SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(text ORDER BY time ASC) as lst from ...

Comment: @duoduolikes . . . Your question is:  "how can I do it in MySQL?".  This answers your question.